# What real java source code implements bridge pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns, bridge

I need to find out some real world instances of implementation of bridge pattern. Can anyone give me some examples? Classes in the JAVA source code would be the best, thanks.

Comment: Iu sed the Bridge pattern exactly once, fifteen years ago, and I've regretted it ever since.

Answer (score 1):

This article has quite clear example 
http://java.dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-bridge

Answer (score 0):

You can find what your looking for on this Wikipedia [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern).